# Проблема со сборкой Vue CLI

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

Всем привет, у меня такая проблема, не билдится Vue CLI приложение, на дев сервере все хорошо было, но когда сбилдил, то в браузере белый экран, в консоле ошибок нет, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: в сервере, который отдает  не тот html, который сбилдился

Comment: Не понял, как это?

Comment: Конфиг добавьте.